# Xamarin iOS - how to get the Contact record designated as 'me' or 'My Info'

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, contacts

I would like to get the Contact record designated as 'me' which is set in

> Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar > My Info

I'm interested in several fields:

> First Name, Last Name, Company, Phone, Email, Address and URL

[Here](http://img.wonderhowto.com/img/13/66/63535060544981/0/siri-exploited-bypass-iphones-lock-screen-browse-contacts-make-calls-send-emails-texts-ios-7-1-1.w654.jpg) is what it looks like when looking at the Contacts list:

On the right side of the list item, you'll see in grey letters "me".

Do I loop through all the contacts looking for a field with the value of "me" or is there a Boolean field that designates this?

I just saw this thread originally posted 6 years ago but with no solid solution - [Is there any way to get the “Me” card from iPhone Address Book API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836190/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-me-card-from-iphone-address-book-ap)

Comment: I don't believe Apple provides any API to find this record.